# How do I turn the text of a button to a variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How do I turn the text of a button to a variable in Swift? 
This is all I can come up with so far, which isn't working:

```
var answer = "example"

@IBAction func Button1(sender: AnyObject) {

    var answer = Button1.text
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get the text from the button and put it in `answer` or do you want to assign `answer` to the button's text?

Comment: Hello, I want to get the text from the button and put it in answer.

Comment: Your question show no research effort whatsoever. At the very least, you should have read the UIButton class reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the title of a UIButton you have to reach its child UILabel:

```
@IBAction func Button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as UIButton // as! for Swift 1.2
    var answer = button.titleLabel!.text
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It sadly won't let me upvote you. I would've had just enough rep to do so but people kept down voting me.

Answer (score 1):

In an action function `sender` is the button that was tapped, so access `sender` as a UIButton and then access the button's text

```
@IBAction func Button1(sender: AnyObject) {

    let theButton = sender as! UIButton
    self.answer = theButton.titleForState(.Normal)!
}
```

Comment: I get "'UIButton does not have a member named 'text'"

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of a label.